# Changes on the site dose not show up after publishing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, divi

I am learning WordPress on localhost. I am using the Divi theme to create a demo site. whenever I edit a landing page, the changes don't show up on the site after publishing. What is the problem? Kindly help me as I am a newbie to WordPress.

Comment: Hi, you should show your efforts first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you properly saving the changes? You must click on Save button in Divi builder (sometimes you must save twice), because Divi builder has a cache method for the builder that throws this kind of problems in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of a WordPress site not updating right away is caching. Try these two steps to resolve the issue.

1. You’ll start by first clearing the browser cache. For most users, this should fix the issue.
2. The second and most likely cause of this issue is poorly configured WordPress caching plugin. Most caching plugins make it super easy to clear your cache with the click of a button.